# Aligning equation including multiline expressions

Tags: math-mode, align, multline

I have a derivation and have problems getting it to look nice. The derivation goes over several lines, so I want the `=` signs aligned. That is easy either using `align` or `eqnarray`. However, one of the lines is too long to fit in one line. I would like that line to look the way it would look in the `multline` environment, however, with the `=` aligned with the rest of the expression.

This is what I have so far:

```
\begin{align*}
    \chi_{2C}^-(\mathbf k, \mathbf r)=&u_0(\mathbf k, \mathbf r)+e^{i\mathbf k \mathbf \Delta}\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_i(\mathbf k, \mathbf r -\mathbf \Delta)+e^{-i\mathbf k \mathbf \Delta}\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_i(\mathbf k, \mathbf r +\mathbf \Delta)\\
    =u_0&(\mathbf k, \mathbf r)+e^{i\mathbf k \mathbf \Delta}\left(\chi_{C}^-(\mathbf k, \mathbf r-\mathbf \Delta)-u_0(\mathbf k, \mathbf r-\mathbf \Delta)\right)\\
    &+e^{-i\mathbf k \mathbf \Delta}\left(\chi_{C}^-(\mathbf k, \mathbf r+\mathbf \Delta)-u_0(\mathbf k, \mathbf r+\mathbf \Delta)\right)\\
    =&-u_0(\mathbf k, \mathbf r)+e^{i\mathbf k \mathbf \Delta}\chi_{C}^-(\mathbf k, \mathbf r-\mathbf \Delta)+e^{-i\mathbf k \mathbf \Delta}\chi_{C}^-(\mathbf k, \mathbf r+\mathbf \Delta),
\end{align*}
```

I attached a picture of what I would like it to look like. Alternatively one could align the `+` of the second and third row.

[image]

Comment: Please supply a complete example document that makes the above image (possibly without the linebreak on the long equation) probably `split` does what you want, but hard to say without an example.

Comment: First of all, use `&=` instead of `=&`.

Comment: Use `&=\phantom{u_0(\mathbf k, \mathbf r)}+.....` for the 3rd line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two solutions, using `align*` and `aligned`, the latter aligned being used to emulate… `multlined`, since the original multlined, in this context, looks like a petty aligned. I added a small vertical spacing to separate out the aligned/‘multlined’ group.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[upright]{fourier}
\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
 \chi_{2\,C}^-(\mathbf k , \mathbf r) & = u_0(\mathbf k, \mathbf r)+e^{i\mathbf{k \Delta}}\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_i(\mathbf k, \mathbf r -\mathbf \Delta)+e^{-i\mathbf{k \Delta}}\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_i(\mathbf k, \mathbf r + \mathbf \Delta)\\[0.8ex]
 & = \!\begin{aligned}[t]
 u_0 (\mathbf{k, r}) & + e^{i\mathbf{k \Delta}}\left(\chi_{C}^-(\mathbf k, \mathbf r - \mathbf \Delta) - u_0(\mathbf k, \mathbf r-\mathbf \Delta)\right) \\
 & +e^{-i\mathbf{k \Delta}}\left(\chi_{C}^-(\mathbf k, \mathbf r+\mathbf \Delta)-u_0(\mathbf k, \mathbf r+\mathbf \Delta)\right)
 \end{aligned} \\[1ex]
 & = -u_0(\mathbf k, \mathbf r)+e^{i\mathbf{k \Delta}}\chi_{C}^-(\mathbf k, \mathbf r-\mathbf \Delta)+e^{-i\mathbf {k \Delta}}\chi_{C}^-(\mathbf k, \mathbf r+\mathbf \Delta),
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
 \chi_{2\,C}^-(\mathbf k , \mathbf r) & = u_0(\mathbf k, \mathbf r)+e^{i\mathbf{k \Delta}}\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_i(\mathbf k, \mathbf r -\mathbf \Delta)+e^{-i\mathbf{k \Delta}}\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_i(\mathbf k, \mathbf r + \mathbf \Delta)\\[0.8ex]
 & = \!\begin{aligned}[t]
 u_0 (\mathbf{k, r}) + e^{i\mathbf{k \Delta}}& \left(\chi_{C}^-(\mathbf k, \mathbf r - \mathbf \Delta) - u_0(\mathbf k, \mathbf r-\mathbf \Delta)\right) \\
 & +e^{-i\mathbf{k \Delta}}\left(\chi_{C}^-(\mathbf k, \mathbf r+\mathbf \Delta)-u_0(\mathbf k, \mathbf r+\mathbf \Delta)\right)
 \end{aligned} \\[1ex]
 & = -u_0(\mathbf k, \mathbf r)+e^{i\mathbf{k \Delta}}\chi_{C}^-(\mathbf k, \mathbf r-\mathbf \Delta)+e^{-i\mathbf {k \Delta}}\chi_{C}^-(\mathbf k, \mathbf r+\mathbf \Delta),
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A nonstardard usage of `\intertext`  gives the desired result (aligning the third line to the right). Additionally, the spacing of `+e^i...` is corrected.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}


\begin{align*} \chi_{2C}^-(\mathbf k, \mathbf r)&
=u_0(\mathbf k, \mathbf r)+e^{i\mathbf k \mathbf \Delta}\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_i(\mathbf k, \mathbf r -\mathbf \Delta)+e^{-i\mathbf k \mathbf \Delta}\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_i(\mathbf k, \mathbf r +\mathbf \Delta)\\ 
&=u_0(\mathbf k, \mathbf r)+e^{i\mathbf k \mathbf \Delta}\left(\chi_{C}^-(\mathbf k, \mathbf r-\mathbf \Delta)-u_0(\mathbf k, \mathbf r-\mathbf \Delta)\right)\\ 
\intertext{\null\hfill${}+e^{-i\mathbf k \mathbf \Delta}\left(\chi_{C}^-(\mathbf k, \mathbf r+\mathbf \Delta)-u_0(\mathbf k, \mathbf r+\mathbf \Delta)\right)$}%\\ 
&=-u_0(\mathbf k, \mathbf r)+e^{i\mathbf k \mathbf \Delta}\chi_{C}^-(\mathbf k, \mathbf r-\mathbf \Delta)+e^{-i\mathbf k \mathbf \Delta}\chi_{C}^-(\mathbf k, \mathbf r+\mathbf \Delta), \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]